# Should int *p be long int *p instead?

Tags: c

I'm learning c by reading K&R and doing the exercises.  I'm now in chapter 5 which deals with pointers.  I don't understand why the statement:

```
int *p;
```

is not:

```
long int *p;
```

since *p contains an address and there is no guarantee that a variable of type int will be large enough to hold a large address.  Or is there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

int is the type of the object that the pointer points to and not the size of the pointer itself. The size of the pointer is independant of the object it points to

For example:

```
int *p;

double *d;
```

Both `pointers` p and d would "normally" have the same size, but the data that they point to don't have the same size.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments pointers aren't actually "required" to be of the same size.

As John explained:

> For instance, a char
>   * on a word-addressed system may actually be larger than an int *,
>   since it needs to specify an offset
>   into the word. The only guarantees are
>   that void * and char * have the same
>   alignment and representation, that
>   pointers to compatible types have the
>   same alignment and representation,
>   that pointers to struct types have the
>   same alignment and representation, and
>   pointers to union types all have the
>   same alignment and representation

Comment: Pointers to `double` and `int` don't have to have the same size.

Comment: @Carl hmm, I think that they should. Isn't the size of a pointer consistent on a given system?

Comment: Thx Peter.  I guess the compiler knows how big to make *p based on compiler options.

Comment: @Peter:  Data pointer sizes are normally consistent on a given system.  I don't think they're required to be, and I can think of some architectures (not used much anymore) where pointer size could vary depending on what it pointed at.

Comment: `void *` should have the same representation and alignment as `char *`. Pointers to `struct`'s should all have the same representation and alignment. Pointers to `union`'s should all have the same representation and alignment.

Comment: @Peter: Not necessarily.  For instance, a `char *` on a word-addressed system may actually be larger than an `int *`, since it needs to specify an offset into the word.  The only guarantees are that `void *` and `char *` have the same alignment and representation, that pointers to *compatible types* have the same alignment and representation, that pointers to `struct` types have the same alignment and representation, and pointers to `union` types all have the same alignment and representation.

Comment: @David I am not 100% sure about the "required" part, but I think they are required to be consistent on most modern systems at least...

Comment: Interesting ... Thanks for the input guys, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: POSIX also seems to require all pointer types to have the same size/representation (if not, it at least requires `void *` and function pointers to have the same representation).

Comment: C&V: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf,  section 6.2.5, para 27.

Comment: @Peter R:  They aren't required by the Standard, but on all architectures I'm familiar with that I know are used nowadays, they are.

Answer (score 3):

`long int *` means a point to a `long int`.
It doesn't mean a long pointer.

Pointers are separate things and will have their own size.  (dependent on the bitness that you're compiling for)

Answer (score 1):

`int *` is not of type `int`. It is a pointer type. Therefore it will be large enough to store any address. `long int *` is the same size as `int *` -- it's just that you're treating where things are pointed to as different.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pointer to an int (I tend to write as 'int* p'). This basically means that p is a pointer to an int.

The second is a pointer to a long int.

They are both pointers, and therefore the same number of bytes of storage, but one references an int, the other a long int.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse the type of the pointer with the type of what it points to.  The type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`, but the type of `p` is `int *`.